# Can't get uploaded file and download it. flask

Tags: python, flask

I've been trying to get the uploaded file in the post request which my view handles for the form. Currently, this is my code:

```py
filename = secure_filename(form_data.get('video_file'))
video_file = video_form.data.get('video_file')
video_path = '/media/tmp' + filename
video_file.save(video_path)
```

But it doesn't work and spits out this in the traceback `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'`

Here's my form

```
class VidForm(FlaskForm):
    """New Genre Form."""
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[validators.Length(min=3, max=75)])
    description = StringField('Description', validators=[validators.Length(min=10, max=250)])
    video_file = FileField('File')
    submit = SubmitField('Upload')
```

Comment: The snippet is not sufficient but i think you have to access uploaded file as  filenames = request.files.getlist('video_file') which is a list, and you have to iterate or get the first one only if your form does not allow multiple file selection

Comment: +1 to Luv, you should access via files to get the file object vs. string name: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/